# Bus Error: 10 in C Program, cannot figure out why

Tags: c, malloc, strtok, bus-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void split_line(char **fields, char *line);

int main() {
    char *fields[5];
    char *line = "donuts,are,cool,and,tasty";
    int i = 0;

    split_line(fields, line);

    return 0;
}

void split_line(char **fields, char *line) {
    int i = 0;
    char *token, *delim;
    delim = ",\n";
    token = strtok(line, delim);
    while (token) {
        fields[i] = malloc(strlen(token));
        strcpy(fields[i], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        i++;
    }

}
```

I am new to C and have been trying to figure out how to fix this error for the better part of an hour. It compiles but at run-time I get

> Bus Error: 10.

I would appreciate if anyone could lead me to why this is happening and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use the debugger, Luke

Comment: There's a lot of faith here that there will not be more than 5 entries in `fields`. If you exceed the bounds of that it is going to get ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't modify a string literal, it's not legal. Try like this

```
char line[] = "donuts,are,cool,and,tasty";
```

Also, try to learn something other than `strtok()` for this without modifying the input string, because `strtok()` does that and it is why you are getting an error.

As a recomendation, always use `const` for string literals

```
const char *line = "donuts,are,cool,and,tasty";
```

the compiler will help you see that you are trying to do something bad.

Also, you `malloc()` 1 less character than you need. Strings need *length* characters + 1, the last character is the `null` terminator and it's always needed if you are going to use the data as a string, all the *str* functions expect this value to be there, so you need to allocate space for it, and copy it too

```
size_t length = strlen(token);
fields[i] = malloc(length + 1);
if (fields[i] != NULL) {
    strcpy(fields[i], token);
}
```

Comment: that's true, but once again with "wall of codes" questions, there's more to it: `fields[i] = malloc(strlen(token));` isn't allocating enough memory... You cannot answer fully without making it work on your computer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The off-by-one error strikes again!

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi It's practically the C programming motto!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the case that you're allocating incorrectly. If you have access to [`strdup`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup), try using that:

```
fields[i] = strdup(token);
```

You're responsible for releasing the allocated memory eventually.